# SQL Datetime Error : The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql-server

Following SQL code in SQL Server database throws a SQL error:

```
 DECLARE @val [varchar] (20)
 SET @val = '18/04/2014'
 SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(datetime,@val),101)
```

Error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

It works fine with the following code:

```
  DECLARE @val [varchar] (20)
  SET @val = '18/04/2014'
  SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),@val,101)
```

I can understand the reason.In the code, the date val '18/04/2014'
 does not conform to the format expected by SQL Server as set in the SET DATE FORMAT command. What could be the generic solution? I dont want to impose any input validation to enter date in any defined format.Which could be the best solution?

Comment: The database *should* already have the text value in a unified/sane format. Say ISO 8601. Make it the responsibility of the application (or users) that directly use it provide such.

Comment: *"I dont want to impose any input validation to enter date in any defined format."* - Then you are destined to have errors. If someone enters "08/09/2014", do they mean 8th September or 9th August? Unfortunately you need to either use a some kind of calendar control in your UI so the date is not ambiguous, or you need to specify the format.

Comment: The "following code" that works fine simply converts from varchar to varchar so obviously this will work "just fine". I'd be pretty surprised if it didn't. As @GarethD says, you **need** to have some rules or you will quickly lose control. Those rules should be handled by code outside the database, and in the database you should have only DATE or DATETIME columns. **Do not store dates as varchar in the database**

Comment: "I dont want to impose any input validation to enter date in any defined format.Which could be the best solution?". That first sentence just ruled out the best solution!